# Ansible: can not define variable that starts with " / "

Tags: ansible

I have a variable in variables.yml. In my ansible playbook, I would like to use that variable.But it starts with "/" character. Ansible throws the following error.

> TASK [Display all variables/facts known for a host]
>   ******************************************************************** fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while
>   templating string: unexpected '/'. String: {{/forexcbm-r-0.0.1}}"}

When I remove "/" character from that variable, playbook is working properly.Is there anyway I can escape and use "/" character as variable prefix ? Thanks for your attention

set-prefix.yml

```
---
- name: Apigee Ansible Root
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: true
  vars_files:
    - variables.yml

  tasks:
  - name: Display all variables/facts known for a host
    debug:
      var: "{{ proxy_base_path_prefix }}"
```

variables.yml

```
proxy_base_path_prefix: /forexcbm-r-0.0.1
```

Comment: `proxy_base_path_prefix: "/forexcbm-r-0.0.1"` ??

Answer (score 0):

When using the `var` argument of `debug` you have to specify the name of the variable, not the content.

So change your play to:

---

```
- name: Apigee Ansible Root
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: true
  vars_files:
    - variables.yml

  tasks:
  - name: Display all variables/facts known for a host
    debug:
      var: proxy_base_path_prefix
  - name: Alternative display
    debug:
      msg: "{{ proxy_base_path_prefix }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter *`var:`* expands the expression by default

Wrong syntax (if the value of *`proxy_base_path_prefix`* shall be printed)

```
- debug:
    var: "{{ proxy_base_path_prefix }}"
```

Correct

```
- debug:
    var: proxy_base_path_prefix
```

---

Notes

1) It is possible `"to specify the content of a variable"` in the *`var:`* parameter of the debug module. The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    var1: var2
    var2: xxx
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: "{{ var1 }}"
```

gives

```
  var2: xxx
```

2) *`/forexcbm-r-0.0.1`* isn't a [valid variable name](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names).

> Variable names should be letters, numbers, and underscores. Variables should always start with a letter.

This is the reason of the error

```
... templating string: unexpected '/'.
```